# How to bulk update column values based old values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update the column,

```
old value : eerrt  New Value : ddew
old value : 65th   New value : wwee
.
.
.
.
.
upto 250 rows
```

How to do bulk update in MySQL?

Comment: SQL's `UPDATE` operation, by default, already does bulk updates, if you phrase the query as such.  What does the output look like here?

Comment: Bulk update column : https://snipboard.io/XluIqU.jpg

Comment: How to include old value : eere, new value : rrtt in query upto 250 values

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. You might also take a look at INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax, combined with the VALUES option.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can do a UPDATE JOIN.  Create a temp table with the old and new values:

```
create temporary table ValTable (
  old_code varchar(10) primary key,
  new_code varchar(10)
);

insert into ValTable values 
  ('eerrt', 'ddew'),
  ('65th', 'wwee'),
  /* ...247 more entries */
  ('blah', 'ryzj');
```

Then your update can look something like this:

```
update TableToUpdate u
  join ValTable v on v.old_code = u.code
  set u.code = v.new_code
;
```

HTH,
Joe